# Write a program that takes an array/arraylist of integer and finds longest sub array/arraylist whose entries are equal

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

I am trying to solve a problem in a book.I found this question in Elements of Programming Interviews in Java book.

Solution:
For an example if the arraylist = [1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
The output has to be = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

My code does not work:

```
public class SubArraySameEntry {

 public static int subArr(List<Integer> arr) {



      int count = 1;
      int e=0;

      for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
           int m = 0;

           if (arr.get(i - 1).equals(i)) {
                count++ ;
           }
           if (count > m) {
                m = count;
                e = arr.get(i);
           }
           if (!arr.get(i - 1).equals(i)) count =1;

      }

      return count;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1));
      System.out.println(arr.toString());
      int newArr = subArr(arr);
      for (int i = 0; i < newArr; i++) {
           System.out.print(arr.get(i) + " ");

      }
 }
}
```

I tried and spend too much time but couldn't solve.

Comment: Can you explain the output? I'd have expected `[1,2,3,4]` from the title of the question because that's the maximum length of subarrays having equal consecutive numbers. Why is it supposed to be `[1,1,1,1,1]`?

Comment: output  has to be: 1 1 1 1 1 but i am getting 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: Could you add more information about the problem?

Comment: The title says to find the *length* of the longest sub array but the example returns the sub array itself.

Comment: if an arraylist [0, 0, 1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5] the out put will be [4,4,4,4]. I can use hashmap to solve this but i think there is a more efficient solution

Comment: At the end you just print out the first 8 numbers of your sorted array `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]`, that's why you get `0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1`.

Comment: @Tunaki I'd have expected return to be `4`, since that is the length of the *longest* subarray.

Comment: Hi @Tunaki , I know what you mean but that the question to solve.

Comment: Or rather 5 if we don't care about the elements being consecutive @Andreas. So many guesses though, please update the question with explanation of the desired output.

Comment: Fastest solution (no sort): Build map of `element` to `count`. Find/remember `element` with highest `count`. Build result as `count` copies of `element`.

Comment: Sample implementation for any Java version: [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/DfrqL0)

Comment: Just for fun: `Map<Integer, Long> collect = arr.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())); collect.entrySet().stream().max((e1, e2) -> e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue())).ifPresent(v -> System.out.println("Value " + v.getKey() + " exists " + v.getValue() + " times."))` -> Output "Value 1 exists 5 times.". Then do a loop and print 1 five times.

Answer (score 2):

About your code, sorting (`Collections.sort(arr);`) will totally prevent you from finding the solution.

I'll help in pseudocode

```
Given a counter c
A max counter m
A variable for the max element, e
And an array a
For every element in the array a
    If the element matches the previous element
        increment the count c, and:
          if the count c > m:
            set m to c, and e to the current value
    If it doesn't match the previous, reset the count to 1

Then after all this, the result is e, c times
```

Comment: Did you look at the specified "Solution" (2nd paragraph of question)? According to that, the "subarray" is not built from consecutive equal values, just equal values, i.e. input has five 1's but only four of them together, but answer is still five 1's. So you'd only get correct result with your code if you call `sort()` first.

Comment: @weston I need help to solve it. But thanks for the algorithm

Comment: @Andreas yeah I did see that, it's clearly wrong given the question title.

Comment: Everything is wrong as compared to the title, since the answer to the title is 4, i.e. the *length* of the *longest* subarray of consecutive equal elements. --- Not to be confused with "[subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence)", which doesn't rrequire elements to be consecutive.

Comment: @Andreas you are right but I want to get the output. just for practice

Comment: I corrected the title

Comment: Note that you do not need two `for` loops, my solution only has one.

Comment: @mlhazan Don't edit my answer with your question updates, update your question.

Comment: @weston sorry weston but your sudo code does not work

Comment: Update your question and I'll take a look

Comment: the question has been updated long ago. It's a very simple question for people who has over 1k reputation but I am getting out of luck here.

Comment: I mean, you tried to apply my pseudocode yes, well, update your question with that attempt.

Comment: You're right it is simple, but you're doing this for practice, so what would be the point of someone just doing it for you.

Comment: @weston don't take it personally. but stackoverflow is here to help.I could not solve that's why I posted. If you don't like it just move on. Some one may know how to solve it. I can solve it using map but I am trying other way.

Comment: I have no idea why you think I'm reacting badly or taking anything personally I'm not, I'm trying to help. So the main error with your interpretation of my algorithm is the `m` needs to be defined outside the loop and `arr.get(i - 1).equals(i)` needs to be `arr.get(i - 1).equals(arr.get(i))` http://ideone.com/8paHKC

Comment: @weston Thanks for the code. Though it was not my question. The code you gave outputs 4 but it should be 5 so it is not correct. I wanted output [1,1,1,1,1]

Comment: Well you got the question from a book, did the book give that example input and output?

Comment: Apologies, a few of us assumed the question was for a "contiguous subarray", you could sort first, then that would work, but I don't know if there is a better way (probably is).

Comment: There is. Faster than sort, anyway. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432348/write-a-program-that-takes-an-array-arraylist-of-integer-and-finds-longest-sub-a/41432467?noredirect=1#comment70070894_41432348) to question.

Comment: @Andreas yeah I guess O(n) for hash map insertions. And could do better if only insert once for a contiguous run of a number.

Comment: @Andreas which I see you do! but you look up every item, could do this: https://ideone.com/kJ7lYe